# How to download rCharts plots in shiny with downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

In shiny apps `ggplot2` graphs can easily be downloaded based on the `downloadHandler` function. Is it possible to download the javascript visualisations that are produced by means of `rCharts` in a similar way?  If yes, what is the best approach?

Comment: I think you can't same them as images cause rCharts returns a SVG

Comment: I found a twitter conversation between @ timelyportfolio and @ramnath_vaidya. It's possible: http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/8187844. Hopefully this feature will be added to rCharts soon.

Comment: What was the best approach?

Comment: Should be possible with the **dom-to-image** library. Are you still looking for a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the HighCharts capability of rCharts then you can use it's [exporter](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview) feature which has an download capability as demonstrated [here](http://glimmer.rstudio.com/pssguy/CRANcountdown/) ([source](https://gist.github.com/pssguy/5832902)).

If not, you're left with DOM introspection like I ended up using [here](http://rud.is/workbench/). That has no R behind it, but it shows how to find the SVG in the DOM and make it so the graphic is exportable in a couple different ways.

Comment: +1 nice. But I didn't use HighCharts, so this will not be a solution for me.